# Information retrieval in dbpedia using spotlight

Tags: java, information-retrieval, spotlight-dbpedia

I have recently come across dbpedia-spotlight and I want to do an information retrieval. I have a set of queries and dbpedia and using Information retrieval I need to get the output. I was not able to understand the documentation so can you give me a sample code to start working.
I have tried terrier but that was equally difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Terrier is more popular as a research tool, where you can try out various standard IR models against standard test collections, e.g. TREC, ClueWeb etc.

If you want to develop quickly a reasonably functional search system, **Lucene** is the best thing to try. Go through this [Lucene in 5 minutes](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) tutorial. I guess this should be fairly simple to use.